# Check if stream contains data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code...

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){

    // Emit an event where res MIGHT be modified
    // res may have its write() method called
    // it also may have its end() method called
    self.emit('somethingHappened', res);

    // How do I know if res has been ended?
    if(res.hasEnded){
        // Response was written and sent, nothing to do
        return;
    }

    // How do I know if res data has been set?
    if(!res.hasData){
        // Write some data
    }

    res.end();
});
```

- How can I check if `res` has ended?
- How can I check if `res` contains any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if `res` has ended in `res.finished`. If we want to know if some data have been sent I personally use `res.socket._bytesDispatched` for that information. You can see how it works here:

```
    http.createServer(function(req, res){

        console.log('Have we sent data?',res.socket._bytesDispatched>0);
        res.write('HELLO');
        console.log('Have we sent data?',res.socket._bytesDispatched>0);

        console.log('Have we finished?',res.finished);
        res.end();
        console.log('Have we finished?',res.finished);

    }).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working. I'm a little nervous about using `_bytesDispatched` because it's undocumented and may be removed without notice, although it's fine for now.